# Need help finding syntax in SQL developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, syntax-error

i have the following query for inserting values into my Customer table:

```
INSERT INTO customer(Booking_id,First_name,Last_name,Phone,Address,Town,Postcode,email) 
VAlUES
(1,'Elroy','Craddock',01497 3139773','36 Yaffingale Gate','Tadley','RG78 2AB','e.craddock@yautia.co.uk')
```

after running it writes

```
Error starting at line 1,551 in command:
INSERT INTO customer (Booking_id, First_name, Last_name, Phone,  Address, Town, Post code, email) VALUES(   1551    ,'  Leonard ',' Babbs   ',  01959 8159688   ,'  46 Zoophagy Green   ',' Choppington ',' NE41 5DB    ',' l.babbs@sommelier.co.uk ')
Error at Command Line:1,551 Column:86
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

i'v been trying to fix this syntax error for almost a day now! Any help/suggestions are appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your query:

```
INSERT INTO customer (Booking_id, First_name, Last_name, Phone,  Address, Town, Post code, email) VALUES(   1551    ,'  Leonard ',' Babbs   ',  01959 8159688   ,'  46 Zoophagy Green   ',' Choppington ',' NE41 5DB    ',' l.babbs@sommelier.co.uk ')
```

Your problem is here: `01959 8159688`. This is an invalid number literal.

Depending on `Phone` column type, it's got to be: `'01959 8159688'` (if it is a text column), or `01959.8159688` (if it is a numeric column).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `01959 8159688`.
Assuming this is a phone number, and you want to keep the space in order to separate the area code from the rest of the number, you should surround it with single quotes: `'01959 8159688'` - otherwise, it's interpreted as two unrelated numeric literals.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to format your queries like this:

```
insert into yourtable (
field1
, field2
, etc
)
values (
value1
, value2
, etc
)
```

It makes the commas more visible.  It also makes counting easier since you need the same number of fields and values.  Finally, it makes commenting easier if you need to find a problematic part of your query.